# Silencing OpenGL warnings on macOS Mojave

Tags: opengl, freeglut

My code is full of warnings like

> 'glTranslatef' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.14 - OpenGL
>   API deprecated. (Define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION to silence these
>   warnings)

I did `#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION` but that didn't fix the issue. 
I use `freeglut` that was installed by using `brew install freeglut`

Can I silence it somehow?

Comment: Where did you put the `#define`? You have to put it befor you include the header file.

Comment: @DietrichEpp it was right after the header. It's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer that was given since you said it solved your problem. I realize this is an old post, but I just found it, and protocol is protocol

Answer (score 30):

`#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION` must go **before** OpenGL includes, so you can do something similar to this:

```c
#ifdef __APPLE__
/* Defined before OpenGL and GLUT includes to avoid deprecation messages */
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

Another way to workaround the issue is to pass the option `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` to the compiler during the compile phase.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks.